# Soft question - a subset of a Hilbert space endowed with subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question, weak-topology

I am considering a Hilbert space $X$, endowed with its weak topology. I need to work with a subset (but not a subspace) $S$ of $X$.

However I need to endow $S$ with the subspace topology (so $U$ is weakly open in $S$ if and only if there is a weakly open set $V$ in $X$ such that $U=S \cap V$).

I have quite a lot to write about this, and I am worried that the reader will misunderstand when I speak about $S$ with the subspace topology, thinking that I have misunderstood $S$ to be a vector subpspace. I am also worried that when I say subspace topology the reader will not realise it's the one induced from $X$ with its weak topology.

Is there a better way to phrase myself? Perhaps another way to refer to the subspace topology as to not confuse $S$ with a vector subspace of $X$? I am struggling to find a concise and clear way to phrase it.

Comment: The subspace topology is also called the [relative topology](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeTopology.html), so you can use that term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So does this work as a way to phrase what I described above: ``Consider the subset $S$ of $X$, endowed with the relative weak topology.''?

Comment: I guess so, the term "relative weak topology" also appears [here](https://books.google.hr/books?id=Ma31CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=relative+weak+topology&source=bl&ots=Vi1iyehKMt&sig=5QNy89X6kL8GHwReyBIqgV4uOCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja49SN1PHZAhVIVSwKHQsmBtEQ6AEIXTAE#v=onepage&q=relative%20weak%20topology&f=false).